# Use Spock testing library to test POST to Dropwizard resource

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock, dropwizard

I'm trying to unit-test a [resource class](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#resources) in Java's [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/) with the [Spock testing framework](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html).

POSTing a `Todo` to `/` should add the `Todo` to the database and return
the added `Todo`.  The code works as intended when I run it, I just can't figure out how to test it.

I want to verify three things:

1. I get a `Todo` back from the POST
2. I get a OK (200) status.
3. `TodoStore.save` is called once.

The test below only works for item 3.  How do I fix item 1 and 2?

The full working code is available at [Github](https://github.com/jschaf/tododrop/blob/0d91f53e3687b0a83f8d4fbce9ec341a4c14ed6b/src/test/groovy/tododrop/TodoResourceTest.groovy) at the relevant commit.

#### TodoResourceTest.groovy

```
class TodoResourceTest extends Specification {

    TodoStore todoStore = Mock(TodoStore)

    @Rule
    ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
            .addResource(new TodoResource(todoStore))
            .build()

    def "Adding a todo increases number of Todos"() {
        given: "no todos in TodoStore"
            Todo todo = new Todo(1, "title", null, null, null)
            todoStore.save(_ as Todo) >> todo

        when: "we add a Todo"
            def response = resources.client().target("/")
                .request(APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(entity(todo, APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))
        then:
            // HELP: How do you test that the returned Todo is the same?

            // FAILS: Why doesn't this pass, it's returning 204 - no content
            response.getStatusInfo() == Response.Status.OK

            // PASSES
            1 * todoStore.save(_ as Todo)
    }
}
```

#### TodoResource.java

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public final class TodoResource {

    private final TodoStore todoStore;

    @Inject
    public TodoResource(TodoStore todoStore) {
        this.todoStore = todoStore;
    }

    @Timed
    @POST
    public Todo addTodo(Todo todo) {
        return todoStore.save(todo);
    }
}
```

#### TodoStore.java - this is mocked, so it shouldn't matter

```
public class TodoStore {

    private final DSLContext db;

    @Inject
    public TodoStore(DSLContext db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public Todo save(Todo todo) {
        final TodoRecord todoRecord = db.newRecord(TODO, todo);

        // id is determined by database, not user
        todoRecord.changed(TODO.ID, false);

        // url is determined based on id
        todoRecord.setUrl(null);

        if (todoRecord.getCompleted() == null) {
            todoRecord.setCompleted(false);
        }

        todoRecord.store();

        return todoRecord.into(Todo.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: TodoStore is a class : it's always better to use an interface, and inject a mock.

Comment: I went with YAGNI, plus I can mock classes directly with objenesis and cglib.  I only use TodoStore in one place, TodoResource.  I'll make it an interface if I need to, but each Store (really, repository) will be pretty specific to the DB object or view that it represents.  I don't think an interface buys me much.  Since this isn't a library, I have complete control over the dependencies internal to the app and can modify them with impunity.

Comment: i know, it wasn't an answer. and it's not about simplicity, it's about testability

Comment: I am not familiar with Dropwizard but I think that you should create a real integration test (with no mocks) and use instead a memory db for all your integration tests.

Comment: Yep, good point.  I added a couple integration tests yesterday to the repo.  With the unit tests, I'm trying to verify that TodoResource responds as expected.  Since I can do that without a DB I figured I'd put it in unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have double-checked the documentation.

From the Spock Documentation on [Combining Mocking and Stubbing](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing).

> When mocking and stubbing the same method call, they have to happen in the same interaction.  In particular, the following Mockito-style splitting of stubbing and mocking into two separate statements will *not* work:

The solution for my specific example is to stub `todoStore.save` in the `then` block like so:

```
def "Adding a todo increases number of Todos"() {
    given: "no todos in TodoStore"
    Todo todo = new Todo(1, "title", null, null, null)

    when: "we add a Todo"
    def response = resources.client().target("/")
            .request(APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(entity(todo, APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))


    then:
    // How do you test that the returned Todo is the same?

    response.getStatusInfo() == Response.Status.OK

    1 * todoStore.save(_ as Todo) >> todo
}
```

Still not sure how to validate issue #1, that the response returns the same Todo object.